# How to show Legend box same on Label in HighChart for pie chart

Tags: highcharts

How to show Legend box same on Label in HighChart for Pie chart
my Code is here for Label is following

```
      dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px'
            },
            distance:3,
            connectorWidth:0,
            formatter: function() {
                return Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
            }


        },
```

Comment: So you would like to have the same lables in legend as datalables, or something different ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following :

```
    legend: {
        align: 'right',  //you can change it
        verticalAlign: 'top', // also change it
        x: 100, //set as you want
        y: 0 // set as you want
    },
```